Create a column that returns a value chosen by a condtion for each rows
I have a DB on MySql with trucks. I need to return a specific value for each row by this condition:

if the truck has been removed from the circulation within the 3 last years the row must return: R
if the truck hasn't been removed from the circulation within the 3 last years the row must return: ES
if the truck is new the row must return: NV

For the values I have:

when the truck has been put into circulation
if it's have been removed
when it have been removed if it haven't been removed the value is NULL

Example:



registration
added_in_circulation
removed
date_removed




12345
12/03/2023
0
NULL


45678
14/02/1999
1
17/10/2023


91011
24/11/2000
0
NULL



I'm looking for something like this:



Registration
R_ES_V




12345
NV


45678
R


91011
ES



I have no idea how to make this. it's just a part of a query the rest of it is pretty simple it's just this the problem

What RDBMS do you use? And what do you mean by "if the truck is new "? How to decide if it's new?

@JonasMetzler I'm using MySql, I forgot to mention it: a truck is considered new if the the truck has been added into circulation within the 3 years. (I've made the edit on the post)

CASE      WHEN removed = 1 AND date_removed >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR) THEN 'R'     WHEN removed = 0 AND added_in_circulation >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR) THEN 'NV'     ELSE 'ES' END AS R_ES_V

Why should R be shown for truck 45678? According to your description, the correct result for this truck would be ES (hasn't been removed in last 3 years). Is your sample result wrong or your description?

@JonasMetzler My bad it was a bad exmple. I fixed the post.

@BryanDellinger. It's a great solution thank you. I'll just check if there is any other solutions. but don't hesitate to directly respond the question so I will be able to register it as an awnser.

I agree with the CASE proposed by Bryan, just would prefer a variable rather than writing down the same date condition multiple times. See https://dbfiddle.uk/-Jm0zzdD

This is an ideal use-case for the CASE WHEN statement in MySQL.

Per your comment, you specified a truck is new if it has been added in the last 3 years.

You can customize this by changing SET @new_date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR);
Likewise for the other date.


You didn't specify the edge case of a vehicle that is added before the last 3 years but never removed. In this query, that case will return '?' for the column. Modify this query to fulfill your requirement there if it exists.

SET @new_date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR);
SET @old_date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR);

SELECT
       registration,
       CASE
          WHEN removed = 1 AND date_removed >= @old_date THEN 'R'
          WHEN removed = 1 AND date_removed < @old_date THEN 'ES'
          WHEN removed = 0 AND added_in_circulation >= @new_date THEN 'NV'
          ELSE '?'
       END as 'R_ES_NV'
FROM mytable


